# mypy operand types for + ("str" and "None")

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my head around type checking, and i don't understand why mypy is complaining here:

```
import typing as t
import os

env_var_1 = os.environ.get("env_var_1")
env_var_2 = os.environ.get("env_var_2")
some_string = "blah"

if not all([env_var_1, env_var_2]):
    raise ValueError("Missing Vars")

print(type(env_var_1))
print(type(env_var_2))
print(env_var_1)
print(env_var_2)

def type_test(env_var_1: t.Optional[str], env_var_2: t.Optional[str]) -> None:
    print(some_string + env_var_1, env_var_2)

type_test(env_var_1, env_var_2)
```

The code runs fine, this is the output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
ABC
XYZ
blahABC XYZ
```

but mypy complains:

```
> mypy test.py
test.py:17: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "None")
test.py:17: note: Right operand is of type "Optional[str]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This error doesn't make sense to me because the type is not "None" it's a string... what am i missing here?

Comment: the addition does not handle the case where env_var_1 is None (if it's not defined in the environment variables for example)

Comment: Because `env_var_1` and `env_var_2` can *both be `None`*. If either one (or both) are None, then your code would error, and mypy is correctly catching that. You have to handle those cases.

Comment: In case you're not aware, the type `Optional[str]` is the same as the type `Union[str, None]`. Hence the other comments; you've told mypy that the type might be `None`.

Comment: Right, that is why i have the `if not all` check earlier in the code.

Comment: @Nathan ah i see, that makes sense.  So what should i be doing here to make mypy happy?

Comment: Sure, but `type_test` is still defined for the arguments being `Optional[str]`. In this particular case, the arguments are not `None`, but the function needs to be correct in general, not just for one set of arguments

Comment: You probably just want the type annotations for `type_test` to be `str`. I'm not sure whether mypy is smart enough to recognize that `env_var_1` is a `str` by the time you call `type_test`, though; this depends on if it can tell the implications of not having raised the ValueError (i.e. both variables have truthy values).

Comment: i don't think it is smart enough for that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

doing this made mypy happy... not sure if this is a good approach or not

```
import typing as t
import os

env_var_1 = os.environ.get("env_var_1","") ##change here
env_var_2 = os.environ.get("env_var_2","") ##change here
some_string = "blah"

if not all([env_var_1, env_var_2]):
    raise ValueError("Missing Vars")

def type_test(some_string: str, env_var_1: str) -> None:
    print(some_string + env_var_1, env_var_2)

type_test(some_string, env_var_1)
```